# windows 7 network error "the dependancy service or group failed to start"

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, wireless-networking

I can't use any network connection in my PC, and when I try to connect, it shows the following error "the dependancy service or group failed to start"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! In order for us to help you, we need a lot more information than what is provided. What type of network are you trying to connect to? Is there any additional information in the error?

Comment: if you pull up a command prompt and enter: ipconfig /all
Do you see any IP information displayed?

Pull up a command prompt as admin >Start > CMD > right-click run as administrator and enter: 
netsh winsock reset catalog (reset winsock entries)
netsh int ip reset reset.log hit (reset TCP/IP stack)

If no help try entering SFC /scannow in a command prompt

Comment: I solved the problem, I found that all network services were disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that services are disabled, to solve this issue try the following steps :

1. type msconfig in the start menu
2. start msconfig
3. choose services window
4. click on Enable all option